# How to use a nested for loop to create a 1D array of integer pairs on a range?

Tags: arrays, bash

In bash, I am trying to create 1-D array that contains all possible integer pairs on a range from a low value to a high value (i.e. 1 to 2)

I've tried using a nested for loop, however the out put I get is the array of the correct size, but all values are the high value (in this case 2)

I've tried nested for loops, however the array I am creating is not the correct size nor does it contain the correct combinations.

```
for (( i=$low; i<=$high; i++ ))
do 
    range_array[i]=$i
done

range=${#range_array[@]}

range_squared=$(( $range*$range))
new_range=$(( 2*$range_squared))

for (( i = $low;  i <= $high; i++ ));do
      for (( j = 1; j <= $new_range; j++ )) do
          combo_array[j]=$i

done
done

echo "the following is the combo array"
echo ${combo_array[@]}
```

I expect the combo_array to be:

```
1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2
```

instead it is

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's too much work for such a trivial task. Here is a simple and working one:

```
combo_array=()

for ((i=low; i<=high; ++i)); do
  for ((j=low; j<=high; ++j)); do
    combo_array+=("$i" "$j")
  done
done

echo "${combo_array[@]}"
```

Given `low=6` and `high=9`, it outputs

```
6 6 6 7 6 8 6 9 7 6 7 7 7 8 7 9 8 6 8 7 8 8 8 9 9 6 9 7 9 8 9 9
```